# Java Gas Station project coding troubles

Tags: java, eclipse, project

I am a beginner at Java coding. Just started an online class less than 4 weeks ago. Im currently working on a project where I need to

> *traverse a logical decision to determine the need of a customer. Simulate a gas station that has 4 stations...*

After piecing together what I know so far, I came up with the code below. It does have some yellow errors and when I run in Eclipse I only get the print out:

```
welcome to gas station, choose station number 1, 2 or 3.
```

Can I get some help on what to do from here please?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int stations;
    keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Welcome to Gas Station \n");
    System.out.println("Choose Station Number: \n");
    System.out.println("1, 2, or 3 \n");

    stations = keyboard2.nextInt(2);

    switch (stations) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You entered Station 1.");
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("You entered Station 2.");
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("You entered Station 3.");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid Number");
    }
}

private Scanner keyboard;

{

    System.out.print("Choose your fuel type:\n");
    System.out.println("Press 1 for Unleaded\n");
    System.out.println("Press 2 for Unleaded Plus\n");
    System.out.println("Press 3 for Unleaded Premium\n");

    int gastype;
    gastype = keyboard.nextInt(2);

    switch (gastype) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("You Chose Unleaded.");
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("You Chose Unleaded Plus.");
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("You Chose Unleaded Premium.");
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid Number");

    }
}

private Scanner keyboard1;

{

    System.out.print("Enter gallon amount"
            + "Max amount 30 gallons)");
    int numberGallons;
    numberGallons = keyboard.nextInt(9);
}

double totalPayment = 0.0;
double numberGallons = 0;
double Unleaded = 0;
double UnleadedPlus = 0;
double UnleadedPremium = 0;
double tax = 0;
private static Scanner keyboard2;

{
    Unleaded = 2.50;
    UnleadedPlus = 3.00;
    UnleadedPremium = 3.50;
    tax = 3.5;

    totalPayment = numberGallons + Unleaded * tax;

    System.out.println("total gas amount: " + numberGallons
            + "\ntotal payment:" + Unleaded * tax + "\nthank you");

}
```

Comment: `stations = keyboard2.nextInt(2);` - why `2` ?

Comment: "Yellow" lines are not errors. They are warnings, hold your mouse pointer on the yellow line to read the description of the error.

Comment: Are `keyboard`, `keyboard1` and `keyboard2` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing knowledge about the structure of a class and need more practice at indenting / paying attention to bracket, if I remove parts of your code with placeholders, and indent things correctly (which can be simulated by "folding" those sections of code in your IDE, and auto formatting).

```
    public static void main(String[] args)    
    {//Start main method
        int stations; 
        keyboard2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Welcome to Gas Station \n");
        System.out.println("Choose Station Number: \n");
        System.out.println("1, 2, or 3 \n");

        stations = keyboard2.nextInt(2);


        switch (stations)
        {
            case 1:
            System.out.println("You entered Station 1.");
            break;


            case 2:
            System.out.println("You entered Station 2.");
            break; 

            case 3:
            System.out.println("You entered Station 3.");
            break;

            default:
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid Number"); 
       }//End Switch
    }//End Main Method

    private Scanner keyboard;
    {
        //Snip 1
    }

    private Scanner keyboard1;
    {
        //Snip 1
    }
    //Marker 2
    double totalPayment = 0.0;
    double numberGallons = 0;
    double Unleaded = 0;
    double UnleadedPlus = 0;
    double UnleadedPremium = 0;
    double tax = 0;
    private static Scanner keyboard2;
    {
        //Snip 1
    }
}//Class End
```

The sections I've commented with `//Snip 1` are **outside** your main method, java is interpreting these as class initializers.

(see https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/what-is-an-initializer-in-java/)

These are NOT running with your main method, and not actually running at all, as they arn't **static** class initializers.

private Scanner keyboard;
private Scanner keyboard1;
and the other [fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) below `//Marker 2` are being defined in the class instance scope.

You main method, like all main entry points, is static, there is no classes yet initialized, so anything in the class instance scope is not running, and no class initializers have been run.

To fix this, simply delete the //End Main Method bracket, create another at the very end of your class, and everything will be included in the main method again. I recommend auto formatting your code at this point.

Eclipse will complain about the fields, which will now be turned into local variables as they will be defined in the scope of the main method, so you can fix that by removing the access modifier 'private' in front of keyboard, keyboard1. In fact, you can use the same keyboard variable as a local variable for each time you use it, even without making it a field in the class.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** It appears you may have been attempting to split this into multiple methods, and getting them confused with fields. If so, you need to read up on how to declare methods, just specifying {} after a field isn't enough.

In this case `Snip 1` would be marking where you attempted to create new methods. 
you would need to specify them as

```
private static void keyboard1()
{
    Scanner keyboard1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Snip1
};
```

in this case, `private void keyboard1()` has NO relation to `Scanner keyboard1` and can be named whatever is convenient. You would then need to go on to calling this method in your main method. As it is static, you are safe to do so, but if you need multiple gas stations, you would need to make them non static, and initialize an instance.

If you get stuck passing variables between methods, you can either 1. declare them as fields in the class (noting that they will have to be static, since you are accessing them in the static main method, without instantiating a class.) Or pass them as arguments to the method.

Comment: Okay thank you so much I will look into this right now.

Comment: I should probably mention that I left out the top portion of my code, I have this before my public static void:          package example1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwitchDemo2 {

Comment: I made some changes that you recommended to the code but now Im getting keyboard cannot be resolved error messages. I based all my code on examples out of the book so I'm kind of lost right now... not sure about the difference between private static void keyboard and private scanner keyboard or why eclipse doesn't want to accept any of the keyboard =new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: The stuff before main that you left out was pretty easy to assume, but it's good to include so people know you haven't got any surprises lurking.